# metadata.getTables resultset empty in case of mssql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, oracle, metadata

Am trying to pick all table names from under a database.Am using the following lines of code for that.

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData =  connection.getMetaData();
            resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, dbName, null, null);
            while(resultSet.next()){
                        //doing operations - take table name and all that
                        }
```

The problem here is as in case of mysql its working fine, means if underlying database is mysql - no problem. But when the same code i tried with mssql , am getting the resultset empty. Is there any other alternative exists there to fetch table details from mssql database.?

If its ..please provide the distinction to fetch table details under diff database like mysql, mssql, oracle; cause as in my case my database may be any of the above.
Can anyone please help in this.

Comment: Are you getting any NullPointerException when you use MSSQL?

Comment: no,am not getting any exception. But the resultset is empty as in case with mssql

Comment: mysql and mssql takes different connectors...                              com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver for mssql                       com.mysql.jdbc.Driver for mysql

Answer (score 1):

The code for fetching, for EXAMPLE :

```
Connection con = null;
    try {

      Class.forName(
        "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1269;"
        + "user=sa;password=HerongYang;"
        + "database=AdventureWorksLT");

      DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
      ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, null, 
         new String[] {"TABLE"});
      System.out.println("List of tables: "); 
      while (res.next()) {
         System.out.println(
            "   "+res.getString("TABLE_CAT") 
           + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_SCHEM")
           + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_NAME")
           + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_TYPE")
           + ", "+res.getString("REMARKS")); 
      }
      res.close();

      con.close();
```

You can try this link at this page:

[Listing All Tables - getTables()](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/sqljdbc-jar-Table-List.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think following link will help you.

http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/AllTableName.shtml

Comment: OP is looking for a solution in other than MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL installation comes with default databases. One of the database is named 'mysql'. If you use 'mysql' database and try getting metadata ans the table names it give empty result. 
I verified this by creating another database named 'mydb' and then used it to get the metadata and then the table names. It worked in flip.

It seems MYSQL has some issue or restrictions using the default database named 'mysql'